# I need to write a letter to a previous employer requesting a new position

Tags: employer

I left a company I was with for 25 years a little over a year ago.  I have heard that a new position may be opening up in a different division and would like to throw my hat in the ring.  How do I go about writing a letter to submit my name for consideration?

Comment: Welcome to the Workplace Terri. Our site is focused on answering questions and is not a [writing or reviewing service](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2596/25739). If you have a specific question about how to explain or mention something specific in your letter that you believe is [on-topic](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) then please edit your question. You may be better served by searching the web for examples of application letters. Note that in nearly all cases you should prefer email over actual letters, unless you know your industry to be an exception.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this site is all about getting answers. [Asking us to write your letters or resumes for you is not a good fit for our format since there will be no answer that will help future readers.](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2596/25739)

Comment: Agree with @Lilienthal but I don't think you are really asking for letter-writing advice. Perhaps you could reword your question to ask specific things you want to know about re-joining a company?

Comment: Good luck, hope you get the position.

Answer (score 2):

With 25 years in the company, certainly you should have a few avenues to work with. I'm sure over such a long time you made several contacts within the company who can "put in the good word" for you. However, it's still going to be like any other job submission. It'll require a full/updated resume with a cover letter. The leg up you might have potentially would be an internal contact may find out for you to whom the letter should be addressed. If you know anything about the specific position within the company, the supervisor/manager, or other details you can use that information to tailor your cover letter very specifically to that position. Depending on the size of the company, it might not even be a bad idea to drop off the package in person (especially if you're on good terms with the HR folks). A personal touch with some face time and a hand shake can go a long way to putting a little extra "gleam" on your resume.

If, however, you left the company a year ago with a masterful flameout of burned bridges you might just want to pass on this one. Even if you'd be ideal for the job, the working relationships would already have suffered immense damage before you even sat down.

First step for me though, use your internal contacts to learn as much about the position and the team as possible. Then draft your letter as if you were writing those people.